# Python jumping a while Loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I'm, trying to avoid this while loop what is wrong

```
while True:
    start = input("Ok, are you ready now?\n")
    if (start != "yes" and start != "no"):
        print ("Please enter Yes or No")
        else:
            break
elif start =="no":
        continue
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation. Currently the code is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is totally wrong. Your code is not valid.
By the way, there's the correct indented code:

```
while True:
    start = input("Ok, are you ready now?")
    if start == "yes":
        break
    elif start == "no":
        continue
    else:
        print ("Please enter yes or no.\n")
```

Note that it works in **Python3**

Answer (score 0):

I can't edit the question to fix your indentation
but i would guess that you mean why it is not working.
you cannot have elif after else for the same if

the correct flow is 
if
elif
else

so it should be

```
while True:
    start = input("Ok, are you ready now?\n")
    if (start != "yes" and start != "no"):
        print ("Please enter Yes or No")
    elif start =="no":
        continue
    else:
        break
```